# Is there a qmake equivalent of cmake's ExternalProject

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest, qmake

I wanted to figure out how to include googletest in my project. Hence I read the [README](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/README.md) for the installation instructions. Like I understand it there are always three options how to add a library:

1. static linked
2. dynamic linked
3. directly include the source code into your project.

I guess

> This is done by making the GoogleTest source code available to the
>   main build and adding it using CMake's add_subdirectory() command."

means directly including the source code into your project, hence option 3.

They mention that the best way to implement option 3, is to:

> Use CMake to download GoogleTest as part of the build's configure
>   step. This is just a little more complex, but doesn't have the
>   limitations of the other methods.

They do this by making use of a cmake feature called *ExternalProject*:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.2)

project(googletest-download NONE)

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(googletest
  GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/google/googletest.git
  GIT_TAG           master
  SOURCE_DIR        "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-src"
  BINARY_DIR        "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/googletest-build"
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
  BUILD_COMMAND     ""
  INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
  TEST_COMMAND      ""
)
```

As I understand it, the benefit is that it automatically searches for updates when building the project. Unfortunately I have no clue about cmake. And compared to qmake the syntax of cmake is awful. Therefore I am asking:

Is there a qmake equivalent to the ExternalProject of cmake?

Comment: Not what you asked but Qt does support CMake as a build system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is it is `SUBDIRS`
See [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#subdirs) for details.

In subdirectory you can create *.pro file which will build a `gtest` as a library.
If I remember correctly you have to build only two files `gtest-all.cc` and `gmock-all.cc` and add respective include directory.

`gtest` is great, but for Qt where signals and slots are used QT Test Lib should do the job too.

Comment: But can it include a project via a link to github and keep the library up to date automatically? As I understand it, this is the cool thing about cmake external project, or?

Comment: AFAIK `gtest-all.cc` an `gmock-all.cc` are auto generated by script (it combine other sources) and are always up to date. So if you build only those two it will always be up to date.

Comment: Sorry I've a bit misunderstand you. Now I see that you are referring to CMake `ExternalProject_Add` functionality. Sadly there is no equivalent in Qt pro file, but you can use git submodule functionality (or tree) to compensate that.

Comment: Maybe you could make that your answer? Then I could accept it.